# TypeError in zeep (when both choice elements are returned in response)

Tags: python, soap, xsd, zeep, workday-api

I am trying to call "Get_Purchase_Orders" operation in python and it throws below error when response is received

```
TypeError error in Get_Purchase_Orders : {urn:com.workday/bsvc}Bill_To_Address_ReferenceType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Address_Reference'. Signature: `({Bill_To_Address_Reference: {urn:com.workday/bsvc}Unique_IdentifierObjectType} | {Address_Reference: {urn:com.workday/bsvc}Address_ReferenceType[]}) Unexpected error:  <class 'TypeError'>
```

the WSDL file is accessible [here](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Resource_Management/v35.2/Get_Purchase_Orders.html#Bill_To_Address_ReferenceType)

My Findings:

`Bill_To_Address_Data` has two elements (`Bill_To_Address_Reference` and `Address_Reference`) that are mutually exclusive, meaning only one out of two elements are expected (there is choice for `Bill_To_Address_Reference` `Address_Reference` and both tags are coming in response ). Sample XML can be seen [here](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Resource_Management/v35.2/samples/Get_Purchase_Orders_Response.xml).

xml chunk can be seen below as well

```
<bsvc:Bill_To_Address_Data>
 <!-- You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level -->
 <!-- Optional: -->
 <bsvc:Bill_To_Address_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="string">
    <!-- Zero or more repetitions: -->
    <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="string">string</bsvc:ID>
 </bsvc:Bill_To_Address_Reference>
 <!-- Zero or more repetitions: -->
 <bsvc:Address_Reference>
    <!-- Optional: -->
    <bsvc:ID>string</bsvc:ID>
 </bsvc:Address_Reference>
</bsvc:Bill_To_Address_Data>
```

below is xsd chunk for above xml

```
<xsd:complexType name="Bill_To_Address_ReferenceType">
    <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Contains a reference instance or a Address Reference ID for an existing address</xsd:documentation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
        <wd:Validation>
        <wd:Validation_Message>The Provided Bill To Address is Invalid for this Purchase Order</wd:Validation_Message>
        </wd:Validation>
        <wd:Validation>
        <wd:Validation_Message>The Provided Bill To Address is Invalid for this Purchase Order</wd:Validation_Message>
        </wd:Validation>
    </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="Bill_To_Address_Reference" type="wd:Unique_IdentifierObjectType" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Reference to an existing Ship-To address.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Address_Reference" type="wd:Address_ReferenceType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Address Reference ID</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I confirmed this in oxygen when validating XML against the XSD in WSDL or can be accessed [here](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Resource_Management/v35.2/Resource_Management.xsd)

Now what I want is to ignore this error and parse the response in python using zeep.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Much more information required. What fixes have you tried so far? What other options did you consider? Why don't you just use Zeep, if that's what you want to do?

Comment: I am using Zeep. @kimbert I added xml and xsd chunk for you. let me know what more information you need?

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are:

1. Modify the WSDL (the XML schema part) so that both tags are allowed in the same request
2. Find a setting in Zeep that allows you to switch off XSD validation
3. Stop using Zeep, and find another tool that allows you to parse a request without validating against the WSDL

Option 1 is best because WSDL is supposed to be a *contract* between the service and its callers. If you don't validate then the value of using WSDL is greatly reduced.

Comment: I have to download WSDL and modify the tag and use it instead of the one on the web. The next challenge is to use a dynamic endpoint not the one in downloaded wsdl